# Make SCSI Appear as Internal Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, raid

I have the HighPoint RocketRAID 2720SGL Raid card running on my Mac and it shows as an external drive. I would like to make it appear as an internal drive.

Is this possible?

From:

[image: SCSI External Raid]

To:

[image: Internal Drive]

Here is the ouput from my System Profile:
[image]

Comment: Do you just want to change the icon or is there a technical consequence I'm not aware of ?

Comment: There is an eject button next to it on the side panel, and it's really not an external.

Comment: I would like it to be recognized as an internal drive. Appear in the side panel the same as the others. By that virtue, no eject button.

Comment: In what way does the drive not work as external?

Comment: It "works" but it is not on external drive, its Internal. I'd like it to appear as internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the following files?

- /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointIOP.kext
- /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointRR.kext

If so, copy both of them to your desktop, then:

- Open those kexts and edit the Info.plist. Change all the 'External' references to 'Internal'
- Copy the modified kexts back to '/System/Libraries/Extensions/'  from your desktop.

Reinstall the kexts:

- sudo chmod -R 755 /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointIOP.kext
- sudo chmod -R 755 /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointRR.kext
- sudo chown -R root:wheel /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointIOP.kext
- sudo chown -R root:wheel /System/Libraries/Extensions/HighPointRR.kext
- sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions.mkext

After this:

- go to your Disk Utility App and Repair your filesystem permissions.
- Reboot.

Comment: Boom: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl7poeufqe5pj1j/Screenshot%202013-11-11%2022.43.22.png
Has anyone told you you're the man lately? Well, you are!

Comment: The kexts were located at /Libraries/Extensions on my Mac. Running OS X Mavericks 10.9

Comment: To be sure, replace `Libraries` with `Library`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Drobo 5D connected to my iMac via Thunderbolt. I'm running 10.7.5 I'd like to have the Drobo load as an internal to bypass silly cloud storage restrictions with my current provider.

I looked at the HighPointIOP.kext and HighPointRR.kext files and didn't see any references to External or Internal. I should note that they were located in /System/Library/Extensions as opposed to /System/Libraries. Am I accessing the wrong files?

Comment: Hi - and welcome to Ask Different. Your post should be a new question - rather than an answer to a different question. Reposting as a question will allow more people to potentially see & answer it...